# Real polynomial is harmonic iff it is real part of complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, harmonic-functions

> [Exercise 27 (iii):](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/09/22/246a-notes-1-complex-differentiation/) $u:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a real polynomial, $\sum _{n,m \ge 0 ; n+m \le d } a_{n,m}x^ny^m $ in $x$ and $y$ for some real coefficients $a_{n,m}$: Show $u$ is harmonic iff it is real part of polynomial $f(z)$ of one complex variable.
> **I am stuck on $(\Rightarrow)$.**

For $(\Rightarrow)$,We can substitute $x=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}, \, y = \frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}$, to obtain
$$ u(z) = \sum_{n,m \ge 0 , n+m \le d} c_{n,m} z^n \bar{z}^m \stackrel{*}= \sum_{0 \le k \le d} a_k z^k +b_k \bar{z}^k , \quad c_{n,m}, a_k,b_k \in \mathbb{C} $$
where $(*)$ follows by Exercise 27(ii) as $u(z)$ is harmonic.

---

EDIT: I end the proof as follows: $u(z) = \bar{u}(z)$ for all $z$, so
$$ \sum_{0 \le k \le d} (a_k - \bar{b_k}) z^k + (b_k-\bar{a}_k)\bar{z}^k = 0 $$
for all $z$. Regarding this as a polynoial in $x,y$ in both real and complex components, we have $a_k - \bar{b}_k = 0 $ for all $k$. So, $f(z) := \sum_{0 \le k \le d } 2 a_k z^k $, yields $u = \frac{f+\bar{f}}{2} = Re\,  f(z)$.

---

Is above proof correct?

Comment: A polynomial in one variable is just $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z+\cdots+ a_dz^d$ for some $d\ge0$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I think this also gave me an idea of how to prove the problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: What you wrote $u(z) = \sum_k c_k z^k$ is not correct and $\overline{z}^m$ is not a negative exponent but a complex conjugate

Comment: @user1952009, yea I noticed, is the revised version fine?